# Twilio ListMessages

Tags: c#, twilio

I am having trouble getting anything other than a NULL response when trying to list SMS messages sent to Twilio

I am using

var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(thisTWaccountSid, thisTWauthToken);
   var records = twilio.ListMessages();

or

var records = twilio.GetMessage( "SM1d6fff54babe41b58c7901de94e9759a");

and get nothing useful back.

I have been able to use other twilio C# resources OK.

Any ideas?

Ta

JC

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into this same issue with *ListMessages* & *GetNextPage*. It turns out the API on Twilio's side has been generating an "Internal Server Error" and my **MessageResult** object has been *NULL*.

It turns out that the MessageResult object has a "***RestException***" property that will be populated if an error occurs on Twilio's side. While I haven't used twilio.GetMessage(), I would assume it has a similar property.

[This is the error I've been getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Babv.jpg)

Here's what I'm doing to trap the error

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient([AccountSID], [AccountToken]);

MessageListRequest request = new MessageListRequest();

request.DateSent = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-08-01");
request.DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.LessThanOrEqualTo;
request.Count = 1000; // anything higher than this results in an error

MessageResult messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);

//Check for rest exceptions
if (messages.RestException != null)
{
    string exceptionMessage = "Code: " + messages.RestException.Code + "\nStatus: " + messages.RestException.Status + "\nMessage: " + messages.RestException.Message + "\nMoreInfo: " + messages.RestException.MoreInfo;

    MessageBox.Show(exceptionMessage, "API EXCEPTION: " + messages.RestException.Code + " >> " + messages.RestException.Status);
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, messages.RestException.MoreInfo);
    return;
}
```

See also: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/151

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

twilio developer evangelist here.

If you can ListMessages without passing any filters to it, you should get an IEnumerable with information about all the messages you've got into your account. That's not only for one specific Twilio number, but for the entirety of this account.

That will then look very similar to this:

[image]

If you wanted for for example get all the message body sent to a specific number, you would then do something like this:

```
var body = twilio.ListMessages().Messages.Select(m => m.Body);
```

And this would give you an IEnumerable back with all the messages that you could then iterate over to display its contents.

[image]

If you then wanted to get information about a specific message, you would use getMessage passing the message Sid. this would give you a Message object with information as follows.

[image]

The fact that you say you don't see any useful information suggests there may be something wrong with your code, which isn't much at this point suggesting you're having authentication issues.

In that case I would suggest checking that your Account Sid and Authentication Token are correct. You need to be using the live tokens and not the [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) for this.

You can find out more about the C# library [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp#using), but come back and reply on the comments if you're still having issues.

Hope this helps you